How to cancel travel insurance because I did not get a Schengen visa?
How to cancel Axa travel insurance? I have been refused a visa for Schengen.

What about asking direct to your travel insurance?

The obvious answer, from just a 10 second internet search, is to contact AXA. Their FAQs say:

Q: My visa was not granted, can I get my money back?
A: Yes. We will need a proof of the visa denial and we will refund in full.

See also how to ask a good question on Travel Stack Exchange
